# Where can I find the precise-pgdg distribution of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I am working on maintaining some legacy code. Now in the Dockerfile there is a line:

```
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

which fails because the precise-pgdg distribution is not available anymore at http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/. Is there somewhere else where I can find this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck citizen

https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/announcing-apt-archivepostgresqlorg-2024/

There's an announcement for apt-archive which looks like it has precise code.

Having said that, precise hit EOL a while ago and PostgreSQL 9.6 is going the same way. Do yourself and your client a favour and move to something current.